# How to pause an amazon lex bot?

Tags: python-3.x, rest, api, amazon-web-services, amazon-lex

I would like to pause my Amazon Lex bot from responding to the user. I would like for it to keep listening to the conversation but not have it respond to any of it. I understand it would probably have to be in a lambda function. I'd like to be able to call the bot to answer again or have a variable to switch the bot from paused to responding again. Is this possible?

Comment: There may be several ways to create this sort of effect. Before I can suggest one, please give a little more detail. What is the purpose of 'pausing' - what will be happening when Lex is 'paused'? Why is it important that Lex continue to 'listen'? Are you using voice interaction from AWS Connect, or text interaction using Facebook, Twilio, etc, or do you need the solution to work for any/all of those?

Comment: I just need the solution to work for all of these cases. Just a way for lex to almost like freeze in place while another program runs

Comment: OK. But again, what will be happening when Lex is 'paused'? Why is it important that Lex continue to 'listen'?